# Is there a way to get all dependencies of the project via sbt plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to write an sbt plugin, and inside it I need to get the list of all dependencies of current project (with some info, is possible). Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our project we use the update task to get the library dependencies:

```
(update) map {
  (updateReport) =>
    updateReport.select(Set("compile", "runtime")) foreach { srcPath => /* do something with it */ }
}
```

Hope this helps for a start.

**[EDIT]** Here is a simple example how to add this functionality to your task:

```
val depsTask = TaskKey[Unit]("find-deps", "finds the dependencies")

val testConf = config("TestTasks") hide

private lazy val testSettings = inConfig(testConf)(Seq(
    depsTask <<= (update) map {
        (updateReport) =>
            updateReport.select(Set("compile", "runtime")) foreach { srcPath => println("src path = " + srcPath) }
    }
))
```

To use the task just add **testSettings** to your project.

For more about tasks see the [sbt documentation](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Tasks). More information about the update task can be found [here](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Update-Report).

**[EDIT2]** The update task only gets the library dependencies. I never tried out external 
project dependencies (like to a git repository).  Maybe you need something like the following: [find project artifacts](http://pastebin.com/VNy68Vss). The task **allTheArtifacts** finds the artifacts of the project and the artifacts of its project dependencies.

Comment: And how should I use this snippet? Just placing it inside the task doesn't work.

Comment: Not flawlessly enough :( It does not catch uri("git://...") dependencies.

Comment: This answer could use an update to a more recent SBT.