# Is there an easy way to copy all jar dependencies to a certain directory in XSBT 0.11.2?

Tags: scala, sbt

When switching from one of the older versions of SBT to the latest version, we lost our ability to quickly grab all jar dependencies and copy them to a directory. Is there an easy way to do the same in XSBT 0.11.2?

Answer (score 39):

Adding the following to your `build.sbt` copies all the dependencies into a `lib_managed` folder in the root of your project.

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Does that also copy the jars of the other modules a certain module depends upon? (Like, if I have a project containing three modules, and the third module depends on the two others modules, would that give me a `lib_managed` directory containing the entire transitive closure of all libraries that module depends upon, including the modules the other two modules and *their* dependencies in that project?

Comment: @Wilfred Yes, lib_managed will contain every jar required by your project.  That means your direct dependencies and all of the transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

We use a custom task definition similar to this to copy the jars. I have no idea whether this is the recommended way to do it — there's un ugly `collect` in there. Feel free to post improvements (or modify my answer in-line if you want).

```
copyJarsFolder <<= (crossTarget in (Compile, packageBin)).apply(_ / "jars")

copyJars <<= inputTask { (argTask: TaskKey[Seq[String]]) =>
  (copyJarsFolder, dependencyClasspath in Compile) map { (folder, cpEntries) =>
    ("mkdir -p " + folder).!
    //
    // find all dependencies
    val jars = cpEntries.collect {
      case attrFile if attrFile.metadata.keys.exists(_.label == "artifact") =>
        // probably an external jar
        attrFile.data
    }
    val copyCmd = jars.mkString("cp -p ", " ", " " + folder)
    copyCmd.!
    folder
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See also this: [How to declare a project dependency in SBT 0.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703292/retrieving-project-dependencies-with-sbt)

yes, you add

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

and you will see the jars in lib_managed folder

Answer (score 3):

Using *sbt 0.13.7*, *IO.copy* and friends.

1. Define few setting somewhere in your build definition:

   ```
   val copyOutpath             = settingKey[File]("Where to copy all libs and built artifact")
   val copyAllLibsAndArtifact  = taskKey[Unit]("Copy runtime dependencies and built artifact to 'copyOutpath'")
   ```
2. Define behaviour for these settings:

   ```
   lazy val myProject = project
     .in(file("."))
     .settings(
       copyOutpath              := baseDirectory.value / "specialFolderForMyProgram",
       copyAllLibsAndArtifact   := {
         val allLibs:                List[File]          = dependencyClasspath.in(Runtime).value.map(_.data).filter(_.isFile).toList
         val buildArtifact:          File                = packageBin.in(Runtime).value
         val jars:                   List[File]          = buildArtifact :: allLibs
         val `mappings src->dest`:   List[(File, File)]  = jars.map(f => (f, maxDynamicJarDir.value / f.getName))
         val log                                         = streams.value.log
         log.info(s"Copying to ${copyOutpath.value}:")
         log.info(s"  ${`mappings src->dest`.map(_._1).mkString("\n")}")
         IO.copy(`mappings src->dest`)
       },
       libraryDependencies       ++= Seq(
         //...
       )
     )
   ```

Comment: Don't you mean  `copyOutpath` instead of `maxDynamicJarDir` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer to this question helps you: [Is there a way to get all dependencies of the project via sbt plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494872/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-dependencies-of-the-project-via-sbt-plugin/9497148)
This is the easiest way I know of (I'm using sbt 0.11.2).